# How to catch the event when can't loadMedia Android

Tags: android, google-cast

I'm implementing an application sharing video on TV.
I don't know sometimes I can't share video on TV. When It can't share Video, it automatically go to on `onRouteUnselected()`.
I guess the reason is the slow network or the long video (TIMEOUT).
How can I distinquish this case from explicity selecting `Disconect` Button in `MediaRouteButton` to do something specific (eg: alert dialog to user).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've noticed this happens when running ICM, specifically Android 4.0.3.  I haven't seen it in JB 4.1+.  Possibly a bug on Google's side?

Comment: I don't use android-support-v7-appcompat. I modified the source code of android-support-v7-mediarouter to use with ActionbarSherlock. Can this way causes this bug?